# Android: Adding view dynamically in a nested layout

Tags: android, dynamic, view, android-linearlayout

I have an abc.xml with the following structure.

```
<ScrollView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <RelativeView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
  </LinearLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I want to add textviews dynamically to linear layout. Below is my code. I don't get any errors but I am not getting the desired results.

```
LayoutInflater Inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = Inflater.inflate(R.layout.abc, null);

LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linear);

        TextView Tag = new TextView(getActivity());
        Tag.setText("textString");
        Tag.setBackgroundResource(R.color.bg_color);
        Tag.setTextAppearance(getActivity(), R.style.SmallFont);
        layout.addView(Tag);
```

Comment: Why you are using RelativeLayout ?

Comment: I have other views in the relative layout as well like textviews and buttonviews

Answer (score 6):

your xml should be

```
<ScrollView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical">
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
  </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and the java code to add your text view is

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linear);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
TextView Tag = new TextView(getActivity());
tag.setLayoutParams(params);
Tag.setText("textString");
Tag.setBackgroundResource(R.color.bg_color);
Tag.setTextAppearance(getActivity(), R.style.SmallFont);
layout.addView(Tag);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know you have found the answer yet, but I had just come across this problem and I found 1 way.
I think you need to adjust the layout of one bit as follows:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeView>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must give,

```
android:layout_orientation="either horizontal or vertical"
```

to the Linear Layout with id:linear.